# How can I display last updates from mlocate in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, locate

Heloo,
I am new in linux. I am trying to display the last updates of ´mlocate´. So that when I use the locate command it finds items according to the last update of ´mlocate´.

How can I do it?

Thanks for your reponse,
Gerard

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the last update of mlocate. mlocate's database doesn't store any time information. It only stores the full filepath of all the files it finds. Just the file path. Nothing else. When you use mlocate, you're just searching for filenames. Perhaps you could make your question clearer about what you want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean last update to database.

```
mlocate -S  |  head -1   | cut -d' ' -f2 | tr -d ':'  | xargs ls -ltr | cut -d' ' -f6-8
```

Demo:

```
$mlocate -S  |  head -1   | cut -d' ' -f2 | tr -d ':'  | xargs ls -ltr | cut -d' ' -f6-8
Mar 30 04:28
$
```

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly my question.

How about if I want to retrieve the last 10 updates for example?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! That was exactly my question.

How about if I need to retrieve the last 10 updates for example?

BR,
Gerard